# How to NOT report overfull hboxes from a personal command?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, warnings

I create a command to display some symbol in the right margins in a twoside document. The point is that they always bring an overfull hbox warning in my logs whereas it obfuscates the real overfull hboxes.

So I want these false/expected warning NOT to be reported, since there are hundreds of them as I use this command hundreds of times.

Here is the  MWE

```
    \documentclass[10pt,, twoside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}


\newlength{\widthtxt}
%\setlength\widthtxt{0cm}
\setlength\widthtxt{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\widthtxt}{\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\widthtxt}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\widthtxt}{0.5\marginparsep}

\newcommand{\qq}{%
\marginpar[{\hspace*{\widthtxt}\makebox[0pt][c]{$\oplus$}}]{%
\hspace*{-0.5\marginparsep}%
\makebox[0pt][c]{$\oplus$}%
}
}





\begin{document}

iueriuwe
\qq


\blindtext[5]



werrewew
\qq




\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly are you attempting with that `\marginpar[{\hspace*{\widthtxt}\makebox[0pt][c]{$\oplus$}}]....` why not just ask `\marginpar` to go on the other side if that is what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the oversized box in a zero width box:

```
\newcommand{\qq}{%
  \marginpar[%
    {\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{\largeurtexte}\makebox[0pt][c]{$\oplus$}}}%
  ]{%
    \hspace*{-0.5\marginparsep}%
    \makebox[0pt][c]{$\oplus$}%
  }%
}
```

[image]

Here is a simpler version of the macros (I assume that `\marginparsep` is wider than the `\oplus` symbol). Less computations, as you see.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\qq}{%
  \marginpar[{% the brace for being able to use brackets
    \hfill % push the material to the right boundary of the margin par region
    \makebox[0pt][l]{% no width
      \hspace*{\marginparsep}% go to the left boundary of the text block
      \hspace*{\textwidth}% go to the right boundary of the text block
      \makebox[\marginparsep]{$\oplus$}%
    }%
  }]{%
    \hspace*{-\marginparsep}% go to the right boundary of the text block
    \makebox[\marginparsep]{$\oplus$}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

iueriuwe\qq

\blindtext[5]

werrewew\qq

\end{document}
```

Comment: it works well indeed. My code uses `\makebox[0pt]` on both sides and so I already have zero width boxes for both sides of the document. So how can they bring overfull hboxes ?

Comment: I forgot to put @egreg to contact you in the comment above

Comment: @Carlos You had *inner* zero width boxes, but you had `\hspace*{\widthtxt}` that made the `\marginpar` very wide.